# Getting only a value from a JSON string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am sorry this seems like an easy answer but I am not really good at programming, I am trying to get a value from an API, I can get the JSON but I only need one value and the other is unnecessary, this is the JSON: https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/ =>

```
"results": [
{
"index": "aboleth",
"name": "Aboleth",
"url": "/api/monsters/aboleth"
},
{
"index": "acolyte",
"name": "Acolyte",
"url": "/api/monsters/acolyte"
},
{
"index": "adult-black-dragon",
"name": "Adult Black Dragon",
"url": "/api/monsters/adult-black-dragon"
}]
```

and so on,

I am only trying to get the index of each one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of the "index" values?

Comment: @skara9 yes, i am trying to get an array of all the index values

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an object pull the data that you need.

```
const data = JSON.parse(results) // Assuming the variable containing your json is called results

// Make an array of only the indexes
const indexes = data.results.map(v => v.index)
```

Update: OP Requested

```
      const uri = "https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/";
      // Promises
      fetch(uri)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const indexes = data.results.map((v) => v.index);
          console.log(indexes);
        });
      // Async Await
      async function getData() {
        const res = await fetch(uri);
        const data = await res.json();
        const indexes = data.results.map((v) => v.index);
        console.log(indexes);
      }
      getData()
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

i think JSON.parse is making the issue, and i changed my variable to results to avoid confusion

Comment: Can you log the value to the console before you parse it? can you tell me what the data looks like?

Comment: "results": [
{
"index": "aboleth",
"name": "Aboleth",
"url": "/api/monsters/aboleth"
},
{
"index": "acolyte",
"name": "Acolyte",
"url": "/api/monsters/acolyte"
},
{
"index": "adult-black-dragon",
"name": "Adult Black Dragon",
"url": "/api/monsters/adult-black-dragon"
}]

Comment: This is odd, are you sure it's JSON? Where is the data coming from? Can you tell me the data type?
`console.log(typeof results)`

Comment: this is the api i am getting the information from, https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/ 

but i am only taking .results, i don't think i would be able to use .results if it wasn't json

Comment: I'll write it out with a fetch request as well then